# How do I code push notifications internally

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, notifications, push-notification

I've been doing some research about coding notifications  into iOS apps but they are all really complicated and I don't have a server to run them off of. I was looking for a way to have internal notifications. I am coding in swift for my  iOS app. I was wondering what code I would need to create push notifications.  My app is a Calendar app for my school and I would need it so if a person were to want to receive notification before an event takes place in notification would appear on their phone.

Comment: Do you want local or remote notifications (a remote notifications needs a server so you want local notifications) google local notifications. Take a look [here](http://www.appcoda.com/local-notifications-ios8/)

Comment: @milo526  yes I want local notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need Push Notifications, you don't need a server yourself. There are services which do it basically for free, as long as you don't need a really big bandwidth.

One great provider is [Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart). There are great tutorials and a quickstart-guide how to do it.

IF you want local notifications([`UILocalNotifications`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/)), there are some easy tutorials like the one on [appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/local-notifications-ios8/)